# Xcode 5.1.1 Loaded image not blended and covers screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've loaded an image into the iPad simulator in Xcode 5.1.1 (IOS 7) with the following objective c code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
}
```

The image is a blend of a medium blue to a dark blue (medium at top, dark at bottom). When I open the image on my pc, it looks fine. When I open the simulator on my MacBook Air the background is a solid blue. In addition, none of the text boxes, buttons, labels etc I placed in the storyboard show up when I load this image.

What are causing these 2 issues? I don't know if this is a coding issue or something else as I am fairly new to Xcode and objective c.

Comment: Instead of `UIImageView` set your image as background image of `self.view`. Hope that your both problems will solve.

Comment: try this  UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)]; your desired frame.
[backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]];

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I found out the answer to the solid color part - it seems the image I was using was much to high resolution for an iPhone. I also needed to create the project as a universal, not iphone application so the image displayed correctly for each device.

As for the second point, I'll try out your code and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: iPatel - I wasn't sure how to do what you described but according to this youtube video /watch?v=XqX3zCp7yfQ I needed to use this code for my method body:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone320x480.png"]];
    //[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone320x480.png"]];
}